# Last element in a row is not aligning

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootsrap 3 as my CSS framework to style my website.

```
<div class="row">

  <div class="col-lg-4">...</div>
  <div class="col-lg-4">...</div>
  <div class="col-lg-4">...</div>
  <div class="col-lg-4">...</div>
           .
           .
           .
</div>
```

The idea is to add the `col-lg-4` div into one row, and the `col-lg-4` div will automatically move to the next row when it has exceed the width of the row.

In general, it works fine. However, the last `col-lg-4` div of the first row is not aligning correctly. The demo address is: http://imaboy.cn/blog/forums/

Do you have any idea why this is happening?

Here is the screenshot:

http://www.imaboy.cn/screenshot.jpg

Answer (score 0):

very easy. In your first column, last row, you have a col-lg-4 element which has an additional row of text, making it higher. This causes to interrupt the normal float of columns. See images below:

[image: no float]

as you may see, that beige zone is about to collide with the column in the left. See image below for a better view of the issue:

[image: no float 2]

I have added a transparency so you can see the collision and how that rocket column blocks all floats.

**The solution**

just add this to your CSS:

```
.col-md-6.col-xs-6.col-sm-6.col-lg-4{min-height:70px; margin-top:20px; }
```

Now you make sure those columns will have the appropriate height to float with ease (adjust that height if needed). Also, I have added the margin-top declaration to your CSS instead of inline since it's better to have it all in the style-sheet. Also, you should consider giving those columns a name, like myCol so you don't risk to affect columns anywhere in your site and you can target them as easy as

```
.myCol{min-height:70px; margin-top:20px; }
```

Comment: thanks, sorry for my english. I mean the first element of the last column(the "Rocket" icon). It is a bit lower than others.

Comment: and that's exactly what I'm talking about, you can apply the style to that column alone, but it's better to do it in general so all columns behave equally

Comment: could you check this link: http://www.imaboy.cn/screenshot.jpg I think there is mis-understanding. :)

Comment: yes I see it now. While I don't know if this could be the problem, I can see you have an error: all your cols have the `haibugui_forum_list` ID. Remember that IDs are unique, and if you need to re-use elements, you need to use classes, like the one I mentioned `.myCol` or `.haibugui_forum_list` . Please try removing all those IDs and replace them by classes, I think that should solve the issue, because quite frankly, I can't find anything else other than these IDs

Comment: the problem still exist,Very strange! thanks any way.